# What is the sys.columns equivalent object in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Trying to find the columns of a object. Is there any equivalent object of `sys.objects` and `sys.columns` in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.columns
```

You can check the [manual for columns](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-columns.html) and for [information_schema](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/information-schema.html)

Answer (score 3):

Some additional objects:

- `information_schema.tables`  is similar to `sys.tables`
- `information_schema.columns` is similar to `sys.columns`
- `information_schema.views` is similar to `sys.views`
- `information_schema.routines` is similar to `sys.procedures`